# Prove that $\sum_{1\le k \le x}a_kf(k)=f(x)\sum_{1\le k \le x}a_k-\int_1^xf'(t)\left( \sum_{1\le k \le t} a_k\right)\,dt,\,\,\,\,\,x\ge 1$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

If $a_1, a_2, \dots \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is a $C^1$ function in an open set that contains $[1, \infty)$, prove that

$\sum_{1\le k \le x}a_kf(k)=f(x)\sum_{1\le k \le x}a_k-\int_1^xf'(t)\left( \sum_{1\le k \le t} a_k\right)\,dt,\,\,\,\,\,x\ge 1$.

Does my proof work?

Let $a_1, a_2, \dots \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ be a $C^1$ function in an open set that contains $[1, \infty)$. Suppose $x\ge1$. Consider $f(x)\sum_{1\le k \le x}a_k-\int_1^xf'(t)\left( \sum_{1\le k \le t} a_k\right)\,dt$. Then

$f(x)\sum_{1\le k \le x}a_k-\int_1^xf'(t)\left( \sum_{1\le k \le t} a_k\right)\,dt = $

$f(x)\sum_{ k =1}^xa_k-\int_1^xf'(t)\left( \sum_{ k =1}^x a_k\right)\,dt = $

$f(x)\sum_{ k =1}^xa_k-\sum_{ k =1}^x a_k\left(f(x)-f(k)\right)\,dt = $

$\sum_{ k =1}^xa_kf(x)-\sum_{ k =1}^x a_kf(x)+\sum_{ k =1}^x a_kf(k)\,dt = $

$\sum_{ k =1}^x a_kf(k)\,dt$. Thus $\sum_{1\le k \le x}a_kf(k)=f(x)\sum_{1\le k \le x}a_k-\int_1^xf'(t)\left( \sum_{1\le k \le t} a_k\right)\,dt,\,\,\,\,\,x\ge 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think the equality 
\begin{align*}
\int_1^x f'(t) \sum_{k=1}^x a_k dt = \sum_{k=1}^x a_k (f(x)-f(k)),
\end{align*}
in your third step, holds, unless you change the integral to 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^x \int_k^x f'(t) a_k dt.
\end{align*}